# Subfolders in script folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdirectory

I have a ton of scripts in my script folder want to organize the scripts in subfolders.  For example, I moved user_prune script to bg_jobs subfolder.  When I try to run the script...

```
script/bg_jobs/user_prune
```

...from the console I get this error:

```
script/bg_jobs/user_prune:2:in `require': no such file to load -- script/bg_jobs/../config/environment (LoadError) from script/bg_jobs/user_prune:2:in `<main>'
```

Why am I getting this error?  And what do I have to do to run scripts in subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looks like a relative path issue with including the environment. Try adding another ../ to the path on line 2 of the script.

Comment: Once you have loaded the environment.rb (by fixing the relative path) you can also use the `RAILS_ROOT` constant to build absolute paths. It contains the absolute path to the root directory of your rails project. This constant is set in `boot.rb` (which is required in `environment.rb`)